# How to validate values in a mocked async method with xunit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, task, moq, xunit

I'd like to be able to validate the parameters passed to an async method in my unit tests. But since the method is async, the task that is performing the asserts has no affect on the unit test overall. The asserted exception isn't passed to the unit test framework (xunit). I'm mocking my repository methods, which are being called by an MVC IHostedService.

Example:

```
CancellationTokenSource sourceToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

var repositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.BulkUpdate(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<MyDocument>>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((IEnumerable<MyDocument> notifications, bool upsert) =>
{
    // verify all the event Ids are in the newly created Notifications (these will actually all be NULL since we can't set the eventIds in the Event object
    Assert.True(notifications.All(x => x.Detail != null));
    Assert.True(notifications.All(x => x.Map != null));

    sourceToken.Cancel();

    return notifications.Select(x => x.Id);
});

await Assert.ThrowsAsync<TaskCanceledException>(async () => await Task.Delay(20000, sourceToken.Token));
Assert.True(sourceToken.IsCancellationRequested);
```

The example here doesn't include starting up the MVC service, but the Startup creates my IHostedService as a singleton, which also starts it running immediately. It will eventually call this BulkUpdate method, and I want to be able to validate that the IHostedService is calling the BulkUpdate with the correct data. The CancellationTokenSource is used to signal the test can exit since the IHostedService has completed the work I want to be tested.

How the background service is started:
In unit test startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyBackgroundService>();
}
```

We have a method that generates a IWebHostBuilder...

```
internal static IWebHostBuilder GetWebHostBuilder(Mock<IIRepository> repositoryMock = null)
{
    var environment = "Development"; //

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    var configuration = builder.Build();

    var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment(environment)
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Add the repository mocks and the type of user thats needed for authentications in the Controller being tested
                // These will be added before the IntegrationTestStartup.ConfigureTransientServices method runs and adds
                // the repository objects.

                if(repositoryMock != null)
                    services.AddTransient<IRepository>((y) => { return repositoryMock.Object; });
            })
            .UseStartup<UnitTestStartup>(); // This is the Startup of AHENS

    return webHostBuilder;
}
```

That we use in out unit tests to inject mocked repositories for testing of the background services...

```
TestServer testServer = new TestServer(TestBase.GetWebHostBuilder(repositoryMock));
```

This all "works", unless one of the asserts fail (throw an exception). How can I get the asserts to roll up to the unit test to fail the test? Is there a better way of doing this? We have test cases where we want to validate that the mocked repository methods DON'T get called, or get called multiple times. This is a unit testing of multithreaded application problem.

Comment: Ok this is starting to feel like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce and better understand the actual problem. There is currently not enough context in terms of the code provided. Also is this meant to be a *unit* test or an *integration* test?

Comment: The root cause of the problem is provided in the example above. The main problem is that the asserts in the async function provided by the mock do not fail the unit test. I didn't include all my use cases in the sample code in order to keep it simple. I have cases where the mocks are called multiple times, and need to be validated differently based on conditions. I have mocks that need to fail if they are called. These cases are set up by the data injected into the background IHostedService thread. This is question about uni testing multithreaded applications.

Comment: It could just be me nit-picking, but if using `TestServer`, then this is definitely not a unit test but an integration test. Seeing way too many implementation concerns for an isolated unit test.

Comment: The definition of unit test vs integration test isn't pertinent to the question. Calls the tests Fred if you want. The tests are all in memory, can test single pieces of logic/code, and have no dependencies on other systems (mocked repositories).

Comment: I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are trying to assert that the parameters to BulkUpdate are what you expected, which can be done like this...

```
repositoryMock.Verify(x => x.BulkUpdate(It.Is<IEnumerable<MyDocument>>(
    notifications=>notifications.All(n => n.Detail != null)), It.IsAny<bool>()));
```

And then similar for `Map`.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: @MonkeyWrench How did it go?

Comment: I'll have to doublecheck what we did, but I believe we ended up going a different path. Ended up having the mocks set a variable with the data in the test, uses semaphores with timeouts to verify the methods were called, and then validated the data. Ugly but worked.